# How to draw or plot a mesh using the mouse in JavaFX which can then be textured and deformed?

Tags: javafx, plot, mesh, image-manipulation, vertices

I am trying to implement a tool into my application. the tool would allow the user to plot a triangle meshes using the mouse. I have looked everywhere for a way to do this, tutorials, examples, etc and have not been successful. I have seen the  [FXyz library](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/tree/master/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/shapes/primitives) but that does not really simulate What I am trying to accomplish. The goal of the program looks as follows:

**Use Case Sequence:**

1. The user adds a png image to the 3D scene or drags it into the 3D scene using the mouse.
2. Once the image is being displayed the user would then be able to plot a mesh around the image.
3. Once the user has finished plotting the mesh. There would have to be a way to add the image being overlayed by the mesh as a texture to the mesh. The image should look the same after being added as a texture. Is this too hard or beyond the scope of what can be achieve in JavaFX?
4. Theoretically It would then be possible to drag the vertices of the mesh at draggable points and successfully applying transformations to the texture. Would this be possible?

**Images showing what I am trying to achieve**

[image]

As you can see maybe after plotting the mesh the points connecting the vertices can be dragged in order to manipulate or transform the shape of the mesh. If the mesh has a texture over it. would the image then also transform ?

Would this be possible with the [TriangleMesh](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/TriangleMesh.html) class that JavaFX has which by the way there is very little out there which explains how to use it and how the points, face points and texture points work. Very confusing =(.

**Target End Result**

[image]

My question is would the type of manipulation shown in the image above be possible in JavaFX? Can this sort of functionality be achieved using the [TriangleMesh](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/TriangleMesh.html) class or other similar class in JavaFX ? As you can see what I am trying to achieve is really image manipulation I would appreciate knowing if there is another better way to do this.

I unfortunately do not have any code I can share. I just cant seem to produce any regarding this task. I am not asking to be given code or for someone to solve the problem for me. I just want to see examples be guided into the right direction on how to do this and to know if it is even possible or should I just give up on it!

**If you have read this far Thank you so much for your time I really appreciate it.**

Answer (score 1):

I have read your question till the end :-) In contrast to many people here you are at least providing a clear description of what you want to achieve. According to my own experience I would say that what you want to do is easily possible with JavaFX and the MeshView is the way to go here.
You can use your image as the texture for this mesh and you can distort the image by manipulating the vertices of this mesh. I have implemented part of your functionality myself for a project so I know that it works.

Comment: That is so wonderful to hear! Would you mind pointing me towards some resource that provides some information on how to achieve any of this things. Or even individual parts regarding what I am trying to achieve. I am pretty clueless breaking my head at the moment.  Thank you so much.